# Does this Latin book state that the meaning of the Arabic word ةلم is huc?

Tags: translation-check

Does [this](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=BXtFAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) Latin book ([p.471](https://books.google.com.ua/books/content?id=BXtFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA471&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U3vn4l_ovTspB10x0lZkgNb--nN7A&w=1025)) state that the meaning of the Arabic word **ةلم** is '[huc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huc#Latin)'?

I'm asking it because it doesn't understood to me if it's the meaning or maybe the book just gives the [transliteration](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/transliteration) of the adjacent Hebrew word only.

[image]

Comment: The Arabic word mentioned above means join us come with us be with us

Comment: The meaning of the Arabic word هلم is bring forward.
As far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my best guess at a translation:

> Whereas the particle הֲלוֹם (*həlōm*), Arabic هَلُمَّ‎ (*halumma*), "hither", "to here", [pr. appactim?] appears in Genesis 16:13 and Judges 10:7. Thus also Psalms 73:10, even though the Septuagint, Vulgate, and Syriac must be changed.

*Həlōm* does indeed mean "hither" (Latin *hūc*), and it seems *halumma* means something along the lines of "come here!" (thanks to other answerers for this), though *pr. appactim* is a mystery to me; searching for it turns up [only this particular passage](https://books.google.com/books?id=2pwcSYcRrZkC&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=appactim&source=bl&ots=zduSlARMZH&sig=ACfU3U04HiB8tQtCwVoGXY3TnCxqGbUQAg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir9Ijby_zlAhWxJTQIHZmpCOcQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=appactim&f=false).

Comment: Does it mean that such word (هَلُمَّ‎) with such meaning exists in Arabic? I found this one: https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D9%87%D9%84%D9%85/ but it seems that it isn't close.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent I'm afraid I know very little Arabic so I'm not sure. I'm guessing at the vowel marks, too.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent Oh? What is it?

Comment: My mistake. It seems to be an orthographic ligature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature#/media/File:Caslon_Pro_Ligatures.svg - See the lowest raw, first from the left - for such orthographic ligature.